# R: Display a continuous spinner, in the console, while code finishes execution

Tags: r

I would like to display a continuous spinner, in the console, similar to the one created by the code below, while some code finishes execution in the background.

```
library(cli)
sp1 <- make_spinner(which = 'simpleDots')
fun_with_spinner <- function() {
  lapply(1:100, function(x) { sp1$spin(); Sys.sleep(0.05) })
  sp1$finish()
}
ansi_with_hidden_cursor(fun_with_spinner())
```

Below is a sample function that takes a long time to finish execution.

```
slow_function = function(x){
# A slow function that takes 10 seconds to complete.
  Sys.sleep(10)
}    
slow_function()
```

A progress bar could be used instead, but its not the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your function, but you need some way to measure progress, either by iteration or estimation. I suppose you could use a `while`-loop instead.

Comment: @mhovd - I see. I was hoping to find a way to indefinitely run the spinner until the function finishes.

Comment: you could have `working = TRUE` in the start of your function, then `while(working == TRUE) {sp1$spin()}` (pseudocode), then finish with a `working = FALSE`, if you follow.